# roslaunch. Passing parameters via command line

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I am performing the tutorial **Customizing the Stage Simulator** and I am facing issues with the following command line:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_stage turtlebot_in_stage.launch map_file:="~/stageTutorial/tutorial.yaml" world_file:="~/stageTutorial/tutorial.world"
```

When I execute it,  the following erros occurs:

```
[FATAL] [1455317172.700221865]: The world file ~/stageTutorial/tutorial.world does not exist.
```

and

```
[ERROR] [1455317069.732110275]: Map_server could not open ~/stageTutorial/tutorial.yaml.
```

Nevertheless, the directory **stageTutorial** and both files **tutorial.world** and **tutorial.yaml** exist.

This behavior becomes weirder because of the fact that when I export the path of both files to the turtlebot environment variables the launch file behaves as expected. The cited commands are:

```
export TURTLEBOT_STAGE_MAP_FILE=~/stageTutorial/tutorial.yaml
export TURTLEBOT_STAGE_WORLD_FILE=~/stageTutorial/tutorial.world
roslaunch turtlebot_stage turtlebot_in_stage.launch
```

I do not have any clue about what is wrong and it is important to mention that the code was copied from a ros' tutorial without any change. So, here is my question: How can I run the fist roslaunch command correctly?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226503/roslaunch.-passing-parameters-via-command-line/) by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2016-02-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dchang0](https://answers.ros.org/users/25414/dchang0/) on 2016-02-12**:
What happens if you use explicit absolute paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Three steps needed.
(1) change ~ to /home/useraccount
(2) change bitmap "../tutorial.png" to bitmap "/tutorial.png"  in tutorial.world
(3) copy turtlebot.inc to /home/useraccount/stageTutorial

Then it will work.

---

Originally posted by [WANG Jiankun](https://answers.ros.org/users/26361/wang-jiankun/) with karma: 26 on 2016-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zhili](https://answers.ros.org/users/30548/zhili/) on 2017-05-29**:
WANG Jiankun 's advice is useful. But I believe the bitmap "../tutorial.png" should be changed to bitmap "tutorial.png".